# SQLite 3: Mass Data Load Issue: Error 14 Database Not Found

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite

I have an iPhone application that is a data load harness to pre-populate database with data that will be shipped in a separate application.  When I kick the program off I am reading from an XML file and the records are inserted into the database.

Everytime I hit the 247th record in the list the database then returns an error 14 database not found.  If I stop the program, remove the 247 entries from the XML file that were just inserted and I restart the program again... the same thing happens.  The next 247 records will be inserted then a failure with error 14.

I have over 30,000 records to load.  Loading these 247 records at a time is not really a good option.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: I have made a bit of progress on this issue. I tried closing the db every 225 records or so which didn't help.  But if I close after each insert it hums right along.  I am using FMDB wrappers... maybe I am just not using it correctly.  But the workaround appears good for now as this is a onetime use

Answer (score 1):

DB2 has functionality in its IMPORT and LOAD commands that allow a commitlevel.  It may not be the best answer, but check the docs to see if you have a way to commit every 200 rows or so.  This way it's hands-free.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what's wrong there, but maybe you can automatically close and reopen the database connection every 200 records to work around it.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Closing the db and reopening in code doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How are you managing transactions? You probably don't want to insert everything in a single block, but then neither do you want to add every record in a separate block.

Comment: I've tried each record as as it's own transaction as well as inserting blocks of records in a transaction. In either case, when I got to record 247 in the list it failed like clock work.